# How to create a specific upper triangular matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I would like to create in python (using `numpy`) an upper triangular matrix in the form:

```
[[ 1,  c,  c^2],
 [ 0,  1,  c  ],
 [ 0,  0,  1  ]])
```

where `c` is a rational number and the rank of the matrix may vary (2, 3, 4, ...). Is there any smart way to do it other than creating rows and stacking them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r = 3
c = 3
i,j = np.indices((r,r))
np.triu(float(c)**(j-i))
```

Result:

```
array([[1., 3., 9.],
       [0., 1., 3.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are probably more straightforward solutions but this is what I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

c=5
m=np.triu(c**np.triu(np.ones((3,3)), 1).cumsum(axis =1))
print(m)
```

output:

```
[[ 1.  5. 25.]
 [ 0.  1.  5.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```